# Powershell <= v2 Get-Computer that authenticated in the last two months

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

The computers need to be not supported anymore (that's covered) but also need to have authenticated with the Domain in the past two months. I have found the function `Get-Date` but that's supported from v5 and I need at most v2.

```
Get-ADComputer `
-Filter {(OperatingSystemVersion -le "5.2") -or (OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*")} `
-Properties *
```

I have found a blogpost about Get-Date from 2010 so it can't be v5. If I look at technet it says v5. Now I'm not sure from which version it's supported.

I was hoping that the following would work `((LastLogonDate) -ge ((Get-Date).AddDays(-60)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PS2 does not support autoenrollment, this should work fine:

```
$refdate = Get-Date
$refdate = $refdate.adddays(-60)
Get-ADComputer `
-Filter {((OperatingSystemVersion -le "5.2") -or (OperatingSystemVersion -notlike "*")) -and (lastlogondate -ge $refdate)} `
-Properties *
```

Autoenrollment - introduced in powershell 3 - allows you to take an object inside paranthesis to use its methods and properties. In powershell 3 you can just go by `(Get-date).AddDays(-60)` and use the output of that.

Comment: This is wat I was searching for and it works. Right now I'm just a bit confused why this works and the line at the bottom of my question not. It's exactly the same. Right?

Comment: In later PSversions its quite the same, yes. But PS2 does not Support to take an object and use a method or property of it just by writing it inside ().
This feature is called auto enrollment and is introduced with powershell 3

Comment: That's gonna be helpful to know further on, thanks. I'm testing it on a 2012R2 server tho.

Answer (score 1):

How about just use .net?

You can also roll your own by wrapping the above in a function

```
Function get-date {
[cmdletbinding()]
Param([Parameter(mandatory = $false)][string]$inputobject)
    if ($inputobject) { [datetime]:: parse($inputobject) }
    else {  [datetime]::now }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer keeping it in Powershell. I know it's possible but I can't find a good example of it.

Comment: As far as I know, you can easily use code like
$date = Get-date; $date.adddays(-60); If ($lastlogon -gt $date) {do}

Comment: you can use .net objects directly in powershell. there is no reason not to. in fact get-date is a cmdlet written in .net. so my suggestion is still to use the above code in your script. then you get the get-date command.

Comment: @restless1987 I need to use it in a Filter

Comment: @Max What is the inputobject?

Comment: you will need to input the current time. I suppose the code can be changed to not require that and give the current time. see revision @AdrianZ.